Inconveniente con consulta SQL en Access con el lenguaje de programación VBA
Cordial saludo espero se encuentren bien por medio de la presente solicito por favor la colaboración que me puedan  brindar en cuanto a realizar
una consulta SQL Select en el lenguaje de programación VBA que en la sentencia WHERE solicita un requerimiento de un texto que esta dentro de un subformulario:
El fragmento de código que tengo es el siguiente:
Dim sSql As String, Saldoant As DAO.Recordset
sSql = "SELECT [Max(Observaciones)] as Saldo_anterior" & _
"FROM Concepto WHERE Concepto.IdCtaCobro IN (SELECT TOP 1 [RecibodeIngresos.IdCtaCobro] " & _
"FROM RecibodeIngresos WHERE Númdedocidentif='" & [Forms]![frm_ProveedoresRecibodeingresosconcepto]![Númdedocidentif] & "');"
DoCmd.RunSQL sSql

Pero al momento de ejecutar el código, el compilador  me señala la instrucción DoCmd.RunSQL sSql
Y me muestra una ventana con el siguiente error:
Se ha producido el error ‘3141’ en tiempo de ejecución:
La instrucción SELECT incluye una palabra reservada, le falta un argumento o  esta mal escrito, o bien los signos de puntuación no son correctos
E intentado realizar también lo siguiente dentro de la consulta :
sSql = "SELECT [Max(Observaciones)] as Saldo_anterior" & _
"FROM Concepto WHERE Concepto.IdCtaCobro IN (SELECT TOP 1 [RecibodeIngresos.IdCtaCobro] " & _
"FROM RecibodeIngresos WHERE Númdedocidentif= [Forms]![frm_ProveedoresRecibodeingresosconcepto]![Númdedocidentif]);"
DoCmd.RunSQL sSql

Pero igualmente me aparece el mismo error.
Muchas gracias por la colaboración que me puedan prestar.

DoCmd.RunSQL tengo entendido que no sirve para SELECT ... en lugar sedebe usar DAO para los recordset...

No hagas DoCmd.RunSQL. Ese método está reservado para consultas que realizan una acción, como INSERT, DELETE y UPDATE.
En su lugar utiliza DoCmd.OpenQuery:
Dim sSql As String, Saldoant As DAO.Recordset
sSql = "SELECT [Max(Observaciones)] as Saldo_anterior " & _
"FROM Concepto WHERE Concepto.IdCtaCobro IN (SELECT TOP 1 [RecibodeIngresos.IdCtaCobro] " & _
"FROM RecibodeIngresos WHERE Númdedocidentif='" & [Forms]![frm_ProveedoresRecibodeingresosconcepto]![Númdedocidentif] & "');"
DoCmd.OpenQuery sSql

Además, entre Saldo_anterior y FROM te faltaba un espacio.

Gracias por la ayuda pero el momento de ejecutar el código me muestra lo siguiente:
Error 7874: Microsoft Access no encuentra el objeto ‘SELECT [Max(Observaciones)] as Saldo_anterior " & _
"FROM Concepto WHERE Concepto.IdCtaCobro IN (SELECT TOP 1 [RecibodeIngresos.IdCtaCobro] " & _
"FROM RecibodeIngresos WHERE Númdedocidentif='" & [Forms]![frm_ProveedoresRecibodeingresosconcepto]![Númdedocidentif] & "');
Para ello lo que hice fue modificar la sintaxis,debido a que buscando por Google el Error 7874, este sucede cuando el software recibe la entrada correcta,pero genera una salida incorrecta.

Puede que sea algo asi pruebalo
Asegúrate de dejar un espacio antes de FROM en la primera línea de la consulta

Dim sSql As String
sSql = "SELECT [Max(Observaciones)] as Saldo_anterior " & _
       "FROM Concepto " & _
       "WHERE Concepto.IdCtaCobro IN " & _
       "(SELECT TOP 1 [RecibodeIngresos.IdCtaCobro] " & _
       " FROM RecibodeIngresos " & _
       " WHERE Númdedocidentif='" & [Forms]![frm_ProveedoresRecibodeingresosconcepto]![Númdedocidentif] & "');"

DoCmd.RunSQL sSql


Debes editar tu respuesta y formatear el código con {} en el editor.
